# Iterate through next item in NSArray only when Delegate method has finished

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, search, nsarray

I am using OCR ([Tesseract](https://github.com/gali8/Tesseract-OCR-iOS)) to scan a picture. However, Tesseract is not always accurate when it comes to recognising words and words like "kitchen" and "potato" may be recognised as "k1thn" and "oolat0".

To 'correct' these incorrectly recognised words I want to use the library [PermissiveResearch](https://github.com/leverdeterre/PermissiveResearch) to search and match agains a predefined list of possible words.

The library works extremely well to my surprise, but there is one downside however. It is build to only search for **one word** in a large datasource. The result of the OCR scan is a NSArray of multiple words.

So the logical thing to do would be to iterate through the NSArray like:

```
for (ScannedWord *scannedWord in inputArray) {
    [[PermissiveResearchDatabase sharedDatabase] searchString:scannedWord.name withOperation:ScoringOperationTypeExact];
}
```

The problem I'm having is, is that the result of the search is caught in a Delegate method (`-(void)searchCompletedWithResults:(NSArray *)results`) that is only being called **one time** when it finishes a search. Even though I'm iterating through the NSArray and calling `[[PermissiveResearchDatabase sharedDatabase] searchString:scannedWord.name withOperation:ScoringOperationTypeExact];` multiple times.

How can I use this library to do a permissive search on a NSArray?

Or do you recommend a different approach (with a different library)?

Comment: Look at the code for `searchString:withOperation:`. It only allows one at a time and the search is done asynchronously. So your loop starts a search but each iteration cancels the previous search and starts a new one. So only the last one completes.

Comment: @rmaddy exactly. My question is how to use this library synchronously, or some other way to allow multiple searches.

Comment: From looking at that library it seems that rather than using the convenience method `searchString:withOperation:` you need to use the underlying operations - then you can queue these on your own queue with their own completion blocks.  If you look at the source code for `searchString:withOperation:` and the example in the documentation - https://github.com/leverdeterre/PermissiveResearch#create-your-first-search-operation you can see how to do it

Comment: You can't use a loop. You need to track the array index and do the first search. In the delegate, process the result, increment the array index, and search on the next word. Something along those lines.

Comment: @Paulw11 the library is too advanced for me to adapt it to my own needs. If someone else could find a way for me that would be great.

Comment: @rmaddy I was just thinking about that. Even though it would probably work, I'd rather have a more 'cleaner' method. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: You don't have to change the library - merely how you use it.  The example in the documentation that I linked to shows how to invoke it with a block rather than the delegate.

Comment: Although I notice that they cancel outstanding operations before starting  new one, so their code may not be thread safe.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm playing around with it according to your advice. I commented out the part where it cancels the operations. So to my understanding (I'm not that familiar with threads) it creates an asynchronous thread for every iteration. If this is the case, then that's good. But how would I know that the last operation has finished? I'm using the results for the tableview datasource and reloading the tableview after every search (there are 40/50 words per scan) doesn't seem very efficient.

Comment: Have a look at the grand Central Dispatch/concurrency programming guide. It shows how to wait for the last task in an operation queue to complete

Comment: @Paulw11 I've been struggling with GCD for an hour now, but still can't get it to work. I've used `dispatch_group_notify` and tried `NSOperationQueue` but I think my implementation is wrong. It would be really helpful if you could post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, and it isn't clear whether the PermissiveResearch library supports concurrent operation, but you should be able to use something like this

```
NSOperationQueue* aQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

// If you find problems with concurrency you can limit the queue to a single operation at a time -
// aQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount=1;    

NSMutableArray *outputArray=[inputArray mutableCopy];

NSMutableArray *operationArray=[NSMutableArray new];

for (int i=0;i<inputArray;i++) {

  operation = [ExactScoringOperation new];

  operation.searchedString = inputArray[i];

  SearchCompletionBlock block = ^(NSArray *results) {
        @synchronized(outputArray) {
            outputArray[i]=results[0];
        }
  };

  [operation setCustomCompletionBlock:block];
  [operationArray addObject:operation];

}

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [aQueue addOperations:operationArray waitUntilFinished:YES];

    // Output array now contains the updated words.
    // Perform any UI updates on the main queue
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you start the matching with only one word from `inputArray` and continue the rest of the array from the delegate method?

START:

```
self.copyArray = [inputArray mutableCopy];
NSDictionary * scannedWord = [self.copyArray objectAtIndex:0];
[copyArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
[[PermissiveResearchDatabase sharedDatabase] searchString:scannedWord.name withOperation:ScoringOperationTypeExact];
```

INSIDE DELEGATE (on success or error continue to process the inputArray

```
if(self.copyArray.count > 0)
{
    NSDictionary * scannedWord = [self.copyArray objectAtIndex:0];
    [copyArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [[PermissiveResearchDatabase sharedDatabase] searchString:scannedWord.name withOperation:ScoringOperationTypeExact];
}
```

This way, you will be iterating inputArray elements Scynhronously and no element will be omitted in my opinion.

By the way i don't have `xcode` so there migth be typos in the code

Comment: @rmaddy suggested that in the comments and while it would work I'd much rather take a 'cleaner' approach with the code block option.

Comment: I guess I did not expand all the comments. Sorry. A cleaner way (which is using `NSOperationQueue` and setting `maxConcurrentOperationCount` to 1) is kind of overkill for your need in my opinion

Comment: There is a method called `addDependency` for `NSInvocationOperation` which might allow you to add each operations finishing as a dependency to start the next. If you like this style, i can share code.